# Java Bytecode BUG: Packages get compiled twice

Tags: java, maven, edit, bytecode

I got the weirdest bug ever. Whenever I try to edit the bytecode of a program I write, or the maven shade plugin adds packages into my jar file after compile, the folder get compiled and put in the jar twice. Heres a picture of it: [Screenshot](http://i.gyazo.com/881bad7b6ecb293de968ac37f0eea164.png)

When I unzip the files, they appear as a folder and I can open them up using the windows explorer. The programs still work, but its weird to make my programs public with this files/folders inside the jar. This bug does not only appear using maven.

I tried to reinstall my JDK and JRE, now I'm on the windows technical preview on the same PC but on another hard drive and it still happens both on my Windows 7 and Windows Technical Preview (10). Have you any ideas which might fix this bug?

Comment: Your files are not appearing twice. You're seeing the name once as a directory, and once as a file. I suspect that either the file or the directory actually has a space or other non-visible character in the filename, since you shouldn't get two objects with the same directory with the same name.

Comment: Thats what I dont understand, when I unzip the "file", it appears to be a folder and I can open it. In there are all my packages and my compiled code aswell as in the folder shown by winrar.

Comment: Sounds like what it's doing is showing you both the zipfile and a "virtual directory" of the zipfile's contents, automatically unpacked for you when you navigate into them. (I don't use winrar, so this is a guess.) If so, they could have chosen a more intuitive way to display it... oh well.

Comment: Wow, I just tried using 7-ZIP, the "files" are no longer there. Thabks for your help! Never using WinRar again...